# hbase: For major compaction config does not take effect

Tags: hbase, data-compaction

I have do the config ：habse.offpeak.end.hour:22 ,hbase.offpeak.start.hour: 18.hbase.hregion.majorcompaction: 86400000.but hbase still do major compaction in random time ,like:9:00 ,13:55 and so on.
can you tell me how to config hbase do major compaction in offpeak time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want major_compaction to take effect in idle time.so i config the hbase.offpeak.....,but hbase still do major_compaction in busy time，can you tell 
How to configure hbase to do major_compaction at a fixed time

Answer (score 0):

you can check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8329,
I think the hbase.offpeak.start.hour will not change the major compaction time.